# Ways of calling tested actions zendFrameWork

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2

when I'm calling an action in a controller to be tested, what is the difference between typing:

```
 dispatch('project/controller/action')
```

and

```
 $controller = new controller();
 $controller->action();
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Calling a Controller like this will not initiate any dispatching things of the MVC Workflow.

Answer (score 1):

ZF2 is providing a special class that instanciate your action controller to test it. I suggest you to read [Unit Testing a Zend Framework 2 application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/tutorials/unittesting.html) on the ZF website, this is the doc of 2.2 that is clearer and different than the 2.0 doc regarding unit testing, because 2.0 does not have `Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase`

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have read the ZF2 documentation 2.2 and i am actually extending the same class. the problem is when i chose the second approach, i have then to fake a log in and mock the Acl while everything works just fine with dispatching, i wanted to know how each one of these ways works and how should i choose between them?

Comment: Personnally I use the following approach : I mock user and acl (I use ZfcUser and BjyAuthorize) because I need to test an action when I am a guest, a user or an admin without connecting to database or depending from authentification. I Mock the DB because I don't want to read/write in database from my action test. I have other tests just for my model. Globally I mock every external feature that influence the environnement. I try to keep testing simple and isolated functionnality, testing output while good and bad datas are input